# Difference between cryptopts and crypttab

Tags: luks, cryptsetup, crypttab

I'm setting up an encrypted root fs, which I've done before, but this time I'm using a PGP-encrypted keyfile with a symmetric password to familiarize myself with the process.

There are two places where configuration of encrypted roots seems to occur, in the kernel init options under `cryptopts`, and in `/etc/crypttab`, which seems to be used  by `mkinitramfs` to bake certain things into the initramfs.

It's kind of cumbersome to update things in both places; after all, what's the point of having it in two places if the one suffices? I do see the value of having things in `/etc/crypttab`, as the initramfs can be generated differently with different hooks and scripts if a LUKS volume is present.

Using a previous example emended for this question, here's my crypttab:

```
picrypt /dev/mmcblk0p2 /boot/diskkey.gpg luks,keyscript=/lib/cryptsetup/scripts/decrypt_gnupg
```

Presumably, this tells the initramfs that `/dev/mmcblk0p2` should be decrypted to use the name `picrypt`, specifying that we want to use `luks` and to pass the `/boot/diskkey.gpg` file to the `/lib/cryptsetup/scripts/decrypt_gnupg` script to generate a passphrase for the volume.

Next, here are my cryptopts from my kernel init line:

```
cryptopts=target=picrypt,source=/dev/mmcblk0p2,lvm=pi
```

Again, we're re-specifying that `/dev/mmcblk0p2` creates `picrypt`, and in this case we're also telling it that there's an LVM volume inside called `pi` which it should wait for before trying to mount the root filesystem specified by the `root=/dev/mapper/pi-root` kernel parameter.

This setup isn't working, strangely enough, as it seems to be ignoring the crypttab's key file and key script parameters and not prompting for the GPG symmetric key passphrase, rather directly for a key. I'm going to emend my script to include `keyscript` and `keyfile` in `cryptopts`, but *why* must I do this?

Is there a way to include all of this (or at least most of it) in `/etc/crypttab` and not duplicate everything in the kernel init line? It's kind of ridiculous to have to change everything twice. Do these different sources simply provide different functions, crypttab in the form of hooks and cryptopts in the form of actual parameters to cryptsetup?

Answer (score 5):

Wow. This took me nearly two days to figure out how this all works in Debian/stretch (although I have done this all before). I stumbled over your question and kept it open to answer this in case I find the answer.

And yes there is a [`crypttab(5)`](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/cryptsetup/crypttab.5.en.html) option `initramfs` which does excactly what you are asking for:

> initramfs
>
> The initramfs hook processes the root device, any resume devices and
>   any devices with the “initramfs” option set. These devices are
>   processed within the initramfs stage of boot. As an example, that
>   allows the use of remote unlocking using dropbear.

(Believe it or not, I found this option just by chance by reading a [TODO-File](https://salsa.debian.org/cryptsetup-team/cryptsetup/blob/7fdec2552ee2e370f41babdcfd964cec9029ca8c/debian/TODO.md) in the cryptsetup source.)

So your `crypttab` line should look like this:

`picrypt /dev/mmcblk0p2 /boot/diskkey.gpg luks,keyscript=/lib/cryptsetup/scripts/decrypt_gnupg,initramfs`

One more thing: The cryptsetup modules are only added to the initramfs image "when there is a device that needs to be unlocked at initramfs stage (such as root or resume devices)" (See: [`cryptroot-conf`](https://salsa.debian.org/cryptsetup-team/cryptsetup/blob/fc0608e3b3b35807fd75db5ed353f26e3ecb7ee0/debian/initramfs/cryptroot-conf) hook; recently [renamed](https://salsa.debian.org/cryptsetup-team/cryptsetup/commit/f4619d9863fbcd20e16148cff1acc4464cb90d54) to just [`conf-hook`](https://salsa.debian.org/cryptsetup-team/cryptsetup/blob/7fdec2552ee2e370f41babdcfd964cec9029ca8c/debian/initramfs/conf-hook)). But this currently only works (reliably) if the root device is not in an LVM. To force the cryptsetup modules to the initramfs image I had to set `CRYPTSETUP=y` in `/etc/cryptsetup-initramfs/conf-hook`.

In any case you have to run `update-initramfs -k all -u` after changing any of the mentioned files.

Comment: _"I stumbled over your question and kept it open to answer this in case I find the answer."_ That's how you do it. Great job!

Comment: Backlink to related answer: https://askubuntu.com/questions/381624/lvm-on-encrypted-partition-drops-me-to-initramfs-root-missing/1043319#1043319

Comment: @nh2: Thank you for updating my answer. It's quite fascinating that the rename from `cryptroot-conf` to `conf-hook` took place about 2 weeks after I posted my answer (which is now included in Debian/buster).

And what's even more fascinating is the fact, that last week(!) the `CRYPTSETUP` option has been removed: https://salsa.debian.org/cryptsetup-team/cryptsetup/commit/06f8c00c908ffd1fa95c4afc78e9cac462d01d91