# How to enable discards on encrypted root

Tags: linux, linux-mint, luks, cryptsetup, fstrim

I have installed system on *ext4 filesystem* on *lvm* (vg name `encrypted`, root is called `encrypted-root`) on *luks*. When I'm trying to run `fstrim /`, I get `fstrim: /: the discard operation is not supported`.

My `/etc/crypttab` contains

```
cryptroot  UUID=5ddb7e3a-dcbe-442d-85e8-359e944d0717  none  luks,discard,lvm=encrypted
```

`/etc/lvm/lvm.conf` contains

```
        issue_discards = 1
```

`/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/cryptroot` contains only

```
CRYPTROOT=target=encrypted-root,source=/dev/disk/by-uuid/5ddb7e3a-dcbe-442d-85e8-359e944d0717
```

(I used `update-initramfs -k all -c` to create initramfs).

`/etc/default/grub` contains

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="cryptops=target=encrypted-root,source=/dev/disk/by-uuid/5ddb7e3a-dcbe-442d-85e8-359e944d0717,lvm=encrypted"
```

I have tried to manually put `rd.luks.options=discard` as parameter for linux in grub. I have tried `refresh` option of `cryptsetup` utility (`cryptsetup --allow-discards refresh`*`device`*), but it does not seem to have one (`cryptsetup: Unknown action`).

Physical device apparently has `TRIM` support, when I run `fstrim /boot` it works (it's same device, just not encrypted).

`dmsetup table` command does not show `allow_discards` for `cryptroot`.

When I boot from USB and manually decrypt (with `--allow-discards` argument to `cryptsetup`) and mount root partition, it works. I have tried to use `--persistent` option, but it said that it couldn't make it persistent.

I'm lost. What should I do to make `fstrim /` work? Something tells me I should somehow modify boot options in grub, but I'm not sure how. I'm also not sure if line in /etc/crypttab is used at all (I changed it to `cryptroot` after install, it seems to do nothing even if I change it).

I'm running *Linux Mint 19.3*.

**Links:**

- I have followed this guide to encrypt system: [link](https://jschumacher.info/2016/11/encrypt-an-existing-linux-installation-with-luks-and-lvm/)
- [Arch-wiki section](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dm-crypt/Specialties#Discard/TRIM_support_for_solid_state_drives_(SSD)) about SSDs and dm-crypt
- possibly relevant: [1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/341442/luks-discard-trim-conflicting-kernel-command-line-options), [2](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/206754/difference-between-cryptopts-and-crypttab)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out problem was on encryption level. (You can run `dmsetup table` as root to see if your device shows `allow_discards`.)

This fixed the problem for me:

- Edit `/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/cryptroot`, add `discard` option for particular device. In my case line looked like this: `CRYPTROOT=target=encrypted-root,source=/dev/disk/by-uuid/5ddb7e3a-dcbe-442d-85e8-359e944d0717,discard`.
- Run `update-initramfs -k all -c`. (Maybe make backup first in case there is something wrong with your config and you don't know about it.)